# App crash when using menu button on Android Tablet

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, tablet

I keep getting a message 'Unfortunatly, [app name] has stopped' when I kill the app from the Android menu button.
I use Unity 5.6.0p4, on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 , Android 4.4.2.

When I use Appilication.Quit(), no problems.
No problem with the back button, or home button, only with the menu / layout button, and only on this device / Android version.

I used logcat, and I keep getting some new logs for the crash case :

`D/dalvikvm(12208): threadid=47: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
    D/dalvikvm(12208): threadid=47: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=1)
    E/dalvikvm(12208): threadid=47: native thread exited without detaching
    E/dalvikvm(12208): VM aborting
    F/libc    (12208): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002fb0 (code=-6), thread 12504 (GC_start_routin)`

I can give the 2 logs (crashing or normal behaviour) if necessary..

Thanks in advance !